# Ajax Partial View Facebook Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

Good Night Everyone,

I am developing an application integrated with Facebook and my goal is :

1 ) Perform a search by name and display the result in a partial view without page reload

My problem :

I managed to run all the update mechanism of Partial View via ajax without reaload the page without the information from Facebook ! However when I try to do this with the information from facebook ( used as reference facebook birthday ) he makes the operation of filtering properly, however performs reload the entire page loads and only Partial View .

I noticed that this happens when I use the " decorate" [ FacebookAuthorize ( ) ] , and when they do not have the facebookcontext and void .

Below is my "action " :

```
    [ FacebookAuthorize ( "email" , " friends_birthday " ) ]
     public async Task <PartialViewResult> ListaAmigos ( textoPesquisa string , FacebookContext context)
     {
         var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync <MyAppUser> ( ) ;
         var = friendsWithUpcomingBirthdays user.Friends.Data.OrderBy ( friend = > friend.Birthday ) ;
         user.Friends.Data friendsWithUpcomingBirthdays.Where = (f = > f.Name.ToLowerInvariant () Contains ( textoPesquisa.ToLowerInvariant () ) ). ToList (). ;
         return PartialView ( user.Friends.Data ) ;
     }
```

How can I resolve this issue ? Can you help me ?

Thanks,

Wladimir